# How can I only add a key to an object if its corresponding function argument exists without excessive if statements?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, object

I would like to only add the values to the return object if they hold a value otherwise I don't even want to send them. I know this can be achieved with if statement, but how would I do this if there were even more?

---

As you can see based on the *required key being true*, in the code I have a few of these arguments that *can* but don't actually need to exist. I'd like to avoid adding them if that is true.

I am using MongoDB so if I don't need to add the field I don't want to have to, but the only way I know how to achieve this is by writing a bunch of if statements to check if they exist. Is there a better way to do this?

> The reason why MongoDB is relevant is that MongoDB is a no SQL database so just because something is an option doesn't mean it has to exist.

#### What i tried so far:

*I tried returning undefined if the item doesn't exist this does not work however **Example Below***

```js
    resolve: (_, { input: { createdBy, name, date, description, cost, link, weights, eventApplicants } }) => {

                return dbMutations.createEvent({
                    createdBy, name, date, description,
                    cost: cost ? cost : undefined, link: link ? link : undefined, weights: weights && JSON.parse(weights),
                    eventApplicants: eventApplicants && JSON.parse(eventApplicants)
                })
            }
```

#### Code:

*You really just need to look at the resolve function, but I put the rest of the code there for reference.*

---

```js
createEvent: t.fieldWithInput({
  input: {
    createdBy: t.input.field({
      type: 'mongoId',
      required: true
    }),
    name: t.input.string({
      required: true
    }),
    date: t.input.field({
      type: 'Date',
      required: true
    }),
    description: t.input.string({
      required: true
    }),
    cost: t.input.string(),
    link: t.input.string(),
    weights: t.input.string(),
    applicants: t.input.string(),
  },
  type: 'mongoId',
  // @ts-ignore
  resolve: (_, {
    input: {createdBy, name, date, description, cost, link, weights, applicants}
  }) => {
    let parsedWeights
    let parsedApplicants

    if (weights) {
      parsedWeights = JSON.parse(weights)
    }
    if (applicants) {
      parsedApplicants = JSON.parse(applicants)
    }

    return dbMutations.createEvent({
      createdBy,
      name,
      date,
      description,
      cost,
      link,
      weights: parsedWeights,
      applicants: parsedApplicants
    })
  }
})
```

My Idea:

I think what would work is just assigning these variables to an arbitrary object. Once we do that we can do some kind of object map and set the result to the return statement.

Comment: `return dbMutations.createEvent({ weights: weights && JSON.parse(weights), applicants: applicants && JSON.parse(applicants) })`

Comment: don't you need an else statement if you do that? So for example:
 weights: weights && JSON.parse(weights): "", 
and then the field will be returned, right? Even with your method won't the field still be returned as false?

Comment: You are passing `undefined` now so if you pass `undefined` the property is ignored. If `weights` is `undefined` `weights && JSON.parse(weights)` will work well. If `weights` is an empty string or `0`, you should use `weights ? JSON.parse(weights) : undefined`

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't work I should what I did in the original question this still results in null fields in my MongoDB database

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thing that removes null or undefined values. You may want to tweak the condition to take out empty strings or other falsy things.

```js
const clean = obj =>
  Object.fromEntries(
    Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v != null)
  );
  
let o = { a: 0, b: null, c: '' };
console.log( clean(o) )
```

With it, the resolve function can say...

```
  resolve: (_, {
    input: {createdBy, name, date, description, cost, link, weights, applicants}
  }) => {
    // or promote this in scope to use elsewhere...
    const clean = obj =>
      Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v != null)
      );

    const event = clean({
      createdBy,
      name,
      date,
      description,
      cost,
      link,
      weights: weights ? JSON.parse(weights) : null,
      applicants: applicants ? JSON.parse(applicants) : null
    });
    
    console.log(event); // examine this to prove event is the object you want
    return dbMutations.createEvent(event)
  }
```

Comment: != null
that line is telling it to only return key-value pairs that are not null correct?

Comment: This is excellent If it's cool with you I want to post it to my bog and give credit to you.

Comment: Correct about != null. It rejects null and undefined. Feel free to post it elsewhere with or without attribution. It will be fun to read about it, though. Please leave a link here when you get a chance.